# Cannot Eval js code with yield

Tags: javascript, eval, yield

Here is my simplified code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="testRun()">Click me</button>
    <script type="application/javascript" language='javascript1.7'>
        function testRun() {
            var txt = 'var func = function*() {console.log("hi");';
            txt += 'yield true;';
            txt += 'console.log("bye");';
            txt += 'yield false;}';
            eval(txt);
            func().next();
            func().next();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting the following error:

> 1.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token true

I have seen the following examples:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/eval-yield-waitforseconds-javascript.248463/

http://unixpapa.com/js/sleep.html

but haven't been able to do it myself.

can anyone direct me in the right direction?

### thanks

edit:
thanks for the quick answers but I have encountered a new issue:
when using the func().next(); twice I keep getting "hi" "hi" instead of "hi" bye"
can anyone help me understand what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Use a browser that does support ES6, or at least - as the markup specifies - JavaScript 1.7.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.124

Comment: Actually it's invalid as ES6, missing `function*` (instead of `function`). You need to use some Firefox that does support JS1.7s `yield`.

Comment: @Bergi right.. `var txt = 'var func = function*() {console.log("hi");';` need to do this

Comment: Great, thanks, but now I am encountering a new problem - each call for func.next(); just runs the script from its beginning - i cannot get to the line with the console.log('bye');

Comment: @user1322801: You mean each `testRun()` does run a new generator from the beginning. A second `func.next()` would actually get it to the log line.

Comment: I have updated the question to contain information on my new problem - Bergi waiting for your Insights.

Comment: You're calling `func()` again. You should do  `var iterator = func(); iterator.next(); iterator.next()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work if you change it to:

```
    function testRun() {
        var txt = 'function* func() {console.log("hi");';
        txt += 'yield true;';
        txt += 'console.log("bye");';
        txt += 'yield false;}';
        eval(txt);
        var gen=func();
        gen.next();
        gen.next();
    }
```